# Naming Conventions for .NET / C# / WPF Projects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, naming-conventions

What is a widely accepted naming convention for .NET/C#/WPF projects?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Microsoft has an extensive MSDN article on naming conventions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).

Comment: +1. This is the conventions suggested by Microsoft which is implemented in the .NET class library.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unless I forgot to read something, the article does _not_ describe naming conventions for projects, only for assemblies and DLLs. EDIT: Ok, I just realized that the question itself is ambiguous, and could refer to either project files, or generally everything about a project, in which case your answer would be ok.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some useful links on this subject

[.Net Naming Conventions and Programming Standards - Best Practices](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices)

[Naming Conventions for .NET / C# Projects](http://www.akadia.com/services/naming_conventions.html)

[Naming Conventions & Coding Standards for .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottdockendorf/archive/2005/01/26/361020.aspx)

Goog Luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can see [Philips Healthcare - C# Coding Standard](http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/gemrcsharpcs.pdf) for C#

It look very good.

And of course [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use the tools Microsoft FxCop and Microsoft StyleCop for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listing potentially flammable conventions, I will just tell you that I follow whatever conventions FXCop suggests, with a couple of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

your best bet would be to

(a) look at a number of FOSS .net projects
(b) read [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)